# HealthKit: No matching provisioning profiles found error

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, healthkit

I'm getting "No matching provisioning profile found" error when trying to integrate HealthKit. I've added HealthKit entitlement. I've regenerated the certificates and tried, and still gets the error. Both project and target has the same certificates chosen. I've developer account configured in Xcode. I've refreshed it once the certificate was generated.
Any ideas?

[image: Error screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with HealthKit..!! Check your internet, is it working ? Open your developer portal on browser ? Have you agreed to Apple's new terms & condition ?

Comment: Also check 'bundleidentifier' you are using is registered with your provisioning profile  ?

Comment: First , confirm the bundle identifier of the application and provisioning profile.  Second, under 'Build Settings' select the appropriate provisioning profile for the Target.  Third, enable HealthKit framework under 'Capabilities' section for the Target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got fixed.

1. Revoked a development certificate.
2. Generated a new development certificate.
3. Updated provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if you enable HealthKit service in https://developer.apple.com **after** creation of provision profiles. 
In that case provision profiles becomes invalid.

Solution:
You have to **recreate** provision profiles again from Developer Center.